# Why is "This only works if you cd into the actual directory and not to a shortcut to it"?

Tags: symlink

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/624808/ says:

> A simple way:
>
> 1. `cd` into the directory of the files
> 2. Run `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.mp3; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy ./output.mp3`
>
> This only works if you cd into the actual directory and not to a
> shortcut to it.
>
> More at the [ffmpeg wiki page on Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Why is "This only works if you cd into the actual directory and not to a shortcut to it"?

It works for me when I `cd` into a folder of the files via a softlink to an ancestral folder.

Comment: You have more than 50 rep, you can comment on the answer to ask for clarification

Answer (score 3):

I *think* that the answer is a mix of UNIX/Linux and Windows solutions.

The statement about the code not working if you're using a shortcut to the directory is valid for a Windows environment.

It does not appear to be a valid or necessary restriction when running under UNIX/Linux. It also appears to be an unnecessary restriction for Cygwin too, as Cygwin doesn't work with Windows file or directory shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem occurs in some cases when windows (I assume) sees the [NTFS Links (junction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_links) instead of the destination one, and tries to create the ./output.mp3 files in it (which could fail depending on its location and rights).

You could simply try to do a :  `cd -P the_directory`, instead of simply `cd the_directory`, to have the shell "resolve" and find the "canonical" path, ie the real one, not the symlink one.

(This could be a bit trickier if you have lots of symlinks or maybe ntfs equivalents ...)

Comment: NTFS symbolic links exist. They are totally different to Windows "shortcuts"

Comment: I was referring to NTFS symbolic links, but couldn't remember the proper term ("shortcut directory" was what I chose to replace it with, as it implies it acts like a directory and isn't just a windows shortcut). I will replace with the proper term, thank you!